# .php not working in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The code below used to be Ok. But now I found that browsers do not cache .php files. Why? MY site is on share host. The host never reply. All the other extention files such as html, js, css, png, are fine cached, besides .php.

```
Header unset Pragma
FileETag None
Header unset ETag

# 1 YEAR
<filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|mp3|mp4)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2015 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</filesMatch>


# 2 HOURS
<filesMatch ".(html|htm|xml|txt|xsl|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"

</filesMatch>

<filesMatch ".(js|css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2014 20:00:00 GMT"
Header unset Last-Modified
</filesMatch>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because PHP files can generate different output each time they run, servers don't send cache commands for the output: it might be different next time.

You can force caching by including Cache-control headers in the output generated by PHP, or by specifying the ContentType header from your PHP script.

Which of these is a better approach depends on what your script is doing. Either way, you can implement fine control over caching if your aplication requires it.